# Select Max and Min datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a record as below

```
 Login Time                   Logout Time            User   Shift
2017-04-01 21:30:00.000   2017-04-02 00:00:00.000   I0402   N
2017-04-02 00:00:00.000   2017-04-02 00:30:00.000   I0402   N
2017-04-02 01:30:00.000   2017-04-02 05:30:00.000   I0402   N
2017-04-02 06:30:00.000   2017-04-02 08:30:00.000   I0402   N
```

I want to get the earliest entry time and latest logout time for the user.  How I can do this?

The record I wish to as below

```
   Login Time                  Logout Time              User    Shift
2017-04-01 21:30:00.000      2017-04-02 08:30:00.000   I0402    N
```

Is it possible to do that?
Thanks.

---

Edit

I try before with Max and Min and group by User and Shift, it is work. If it is more than 1 days record, it seem like not work

```
2017-04-01 21:30:00.000   2017-04-02 00:00:00.000   I0402   N
2017-04-02 00:00:00.000   2017-04-02 00:30:00.000   I0402   N
2017-04-02 01:30:00.000   2017-04-02 05:30:00.000   I0402   N
2017-04-02 06:30:00.000   2017-04-02 08:30:00.000   I0402   N 
2017-04-02 21:30:00.000   2017-04-03 00:00:00.000   I0402   N
2017-04-03 00:00:00.000   2017-04-03 00:30:00.000   I0402   N
2017-04-03 01:30:00.000   2017-04-03 05:30:00.000   I0402   N
```

The expected result as below

```
2017-04-01 21:30:00.000      2017-04-02 08:30:00.000   I0402    N
2017-04-02 21:30:00.000      2017-04-03 05:30:00.000   I0402    N
```

Comment: HINT : MIN(),MAX() And Group BY

Comment: Yes it's possible, with a `group by` and `min()`, `max()` functions

Comment: Please mention DMBS you are using.

Comment: ...as long as the user and the shift is always the same

Comment: What's the expected result if a user have several different values in the Shift column?

Comment: Edit your question instead of adding a lot of sample data here. Quite hard to read as this, and don't make it harder to assist you!

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT
 User 
,MIN(Login Time)
,MAX(Logout Time)
,Shift
FROM
   dbo.table
GROUP BY
 User,Shift
```

Comment: Where's the shift column?

Answer (score 0):

I try before with Max and Min and group by User and Shift, it is work.  If it is more than 1 days record, it seem like not work

```
2017-04-01 21:30:00.000   2017-04-02 00:00:00.000   I0402   N
2017-04-02 00:00:00.000   2017-04-02 00:30:00.000   I0402   N
2017-04-02 01:30:00.000   2017-04-02 05:30:00.000   I0402   N
2017-04-02 06:30:00.000   2017-04-02 08:30:00.000   I0402   N                     
2017-04-02 21:30:00.000   2017-04-03 00:00:00.000   I0402   N
2017-04-03 00:00:00.000   2017-04-03 00:30:00.000   I0402   N
2017-04-03 01:30:00.000   2017-04-03 05:30:00.000   I0402   N
```

The expected result as below

```
2017-04-01 21:30:00.000      2017-04-02 08:30:00.000   I0402    N
2017-04-02 21:30:00.000      2017-04-03 05:30:00.000   I0402    N
```

Comment: This is no answer. Edit your request and put this there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query to get the result,

```
 SELECT T1.USER, T2.MAX_LOGIN_TIME, T3.MIN_LOGIN_TIME FROM 
 TABLE_NAME T1
 INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(LOGIN_TIME) AS MAX_LOGIN_TIME,USER FROM TABLE_NAME 
 GROUP BY USER) T2
 ON (T1.USER = T2.USER)
 INNER JOIN (SELECT MIN(LOGIN_TIME) AS MIN_LOGIN_TIME,USER FROM TABLE_NAME 
 GROUP BY USER) T3
 ON (T1.USER = T3.USER);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems what you really want is one result row **per day, user and shift**. So group by these and take min and max time.

```
select min(Login_time) as login, max(logout_time) as logout, user, shift
from mytable
group by date(login_time), user, shift
order by date(Login_time), user, shift;
```

Here `DATE(login_time)` is just an example. How to get the date from a datetime differs from DBMS to DBMS. Look up date/time functions for your DBMS to get the appropriate function.